# Pagination of DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination for my data importing from XML file so I'm not using any database for this I'm just working for XML and DataTable and show it to datagridview . Please anyone can help me how can I manipulate DataTable for pagination of it . thanks everyone !

Comment: Please add what  you have tried so far.

Comment: And please tell if WinForms or WPF